# Declaring EndInvoke for MethodInvoker delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, begininvoke

How do I declare `EndInvoke` for a `BeginInvoke` like this:

```
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() {
  frmPressEnableButton.ShowDialog();
});
```

?

UPDATE: These are the two error mesages that I continuously get during run time
1. `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` can be called on a control until the window handle has been created .
2.   the form that is already visible , can not be displayed as a modal dialog box . Set the Visible property of the form to " false" before calling ShowDialog .

It should be noted that this problem was initiated after I included another dialog box, for which
1. I pass the main form itself by reference
2. I do not call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` for the new dialog box.
This has to keep running in the background.

Comment: Can you explain and show a bit more of what you are trying,i mean more context?

Comment: If this is windows forms, `EndInvoke` is not required unless you want to get a result from the delegate, but `MethodInvoker` has no return value.

Comment: that is precisely my problem. In the present version I have no option of implement `Async`. This was running fine, until an additional call function crashed it. Invoke or BeginInvoke can be called on a control until the window handle has been created - this is the exact error I get. I presume this is due to the non-termination of this thread in the threadpool

Comment: Don't "declare" it, just use Invoke() instead.  Surely you'll want to know *something* about what that dialog produced?  At least the DialogResult?  Invoke() returns it.  If you are not interested at all then there's no point in calling EndInvoke() either.

Comment: I used `Invoke()` function. This is a nested function. So on using `Invoke` it terminates after running this function. I am not interested with the result. It is a simple dialog box that pops up, asking me to press the control switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you try to do but it looks like you'd need an `IAsyncResult` interface to keep the result of asynchronous operation and use it later in your `EndInvoke` method :

```
IAsyncResult result = this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() {
  frmPressEnableButton.ShowDialog();
}); 

this.EndInvoke(result);  // waits until the async call completes
```

Comment: Does this help in terminating the `delegate` thread on completion for sure?

Comment: The solution provided did not work. Can you please check the update and provide a possible solution?

Comment: Solution to what exactly ? You've asked "How do I declare EndInvoke for a BeginInvoke like this" and this is how you do it. if you have other question it would be nice to ask it in a separate post.